# How to get the parameter value from URL in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all i have an url where i need to get an parameter from the url

```
   var URL="http://localhost:17775/Students/199/Kishore"
   //here from the url i need to get the value 199
```

this is what i had been trying but the value is null here

```
  function getURLParameter(name) { 
    return parent.decodeURI((parent.RegExp(name + /([^\/]+)(?=\.\w+$)/).exec(parent.location.href) || [, null])[1]); 
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
     getURLParameter("Students");
     //i need to get the value 199 from the url
  });
```

Comment: `funciton`?  correct that to `function`

Comment: `name + ` why are you concatenating a string to a RegExp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you're looking for since the URL parameter will keep changing:

http://jsbin.com/iliyut/2/

```
var URL="http://localhost:17775/Students/199/Kishore"
var number = getNumber('Students'); //199

var URL="http://localhost:17775/Teachers/234/Kumar"
var number = getNumber('Teachers'); //234

function getNumber(section) {
  var re = new RegExp(section + "\/(.*)\/","gi");
  var match = re.exec(URL);
  return match[1];
}
```

Comment: just one thing, `"\/(.*)\/"` should be `"\\/(.*)\\/"`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is not needed for this, though it could be used. There are lots of ways to skin this cat. Something like this should get you started in the right direction:

```
var URL="http://localhost:17775/Students/199/Kishore";
var splitURL = URL.split("/");
var studentValue = "";

for(var i = 0; i < splitURL.length; i++) {
    if(splitURL[i] == "Students") {
        studentValue = splitURL[i + 1];
        break;
    }
}
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DQrRc/1/).

**Edit**

Based on the comments, indicating that the position will always be the same, the extraction is as simple as:

```
var url = "http://localhost:17775/Students/199/Kishore";
var studentValue = url.split("/")[4];
```

Comment: and as you said the value cant be students every time,so i just cannot equate it to students as you said

Comment: @user2152019, #1, don't change requirements after the question is asked, #2, I don't think you understand what decodeURI does. Look it up.

Comment: i didnt change any requirements here i just said we cant depend completely on the parameter passed

Comment: @user2152019, Well, I'm thoroughly confused then. We're not building AI here. To write a method to extract data from a string, we need the "rules of extraction". They need to be unchanging. So, what are the rules? Will the position be the same? Will the directory (i.e. Students) be the same? What will be the same?

Comment: @user2152019 And what exactly are you defining the "position of the ID will be same" as?

Comment: the value which i want to get will be same position

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent all decodeURI does is unescape some characters

Answer (score -1):

I would do the following:

```
var url = "http://localhost:17775/Students/199/Kishore"; 
var studentValue = url.match('/Students/(\\d+)/')[1]; //199
```

Comment: Tested it on ie8, chrome and firefox. It's returning 199 for them all.